# Wordpress stuck in deleting user

Tags: multisite, users, customization

We’ve run into an issue with our WP Multisite where we cannot delete user accounts. The URL i keep getting is:

http://example.com/wp-admin/network/users.php?action=dodelete

It should look something like this:

http://example.com/wp-admin/network/users.php?updated=true&action=delete

From the looks of it, the info in WP just isn’t updating.

Any idea what's going on with our WP install.

PS : The WP is up-to-date.

Comment: Disable all plugins and try again.